# <c:foreach> jstl tag doesn't print anything

Tags: java, eclipse, jsp, spring-mvc, jstl

The  tag doesn't work... Jsp doesn't print anything... Could I debug jsp page in Eclipse?
view

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<%@ taglib  uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
    <ul>
        <c:forEach items="${listOfMyFriends}" var="friend">
        <c:out value="${friend}"></c:out>
        </c:forEach>

    </ul>
</body>
</html>
```

controller are in MyController.java

```
 @Controller
        public class MyController {

            @RequestMapping(value="/my")
            public String getMyHomePage(Model model) {
                LinkedList<String> listOfMyFriends = new LinkedList<String>();
                listOfMyFriends.add("friend1");
                listOfMyFriends.add("friend2");
                listOfMyFriends.add("friend3");
                listOfMyFriends.add("friend4");
                model.addAllAttributes(listOfMyFriends);
                return "my";
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 5):

Replace the line before the `return` with

```
model.addAttribute("listOfMyFriends", listOfMyFriends);
```

When you do a `model.addAllAttributes(listOfMyFriends);`

`It Copies all attributes in the supplied Collection into this Map, using attribute name generation for each element.`

Attribute name generation is done using the method : [Conventions.getVariableName()](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/2.5.x/api/org/springframework/core/Conventions.html#getVariableName%28java.lang.Object%29)

So, if you are not certain what will be the `generated attribute name`, use

```
 model.addAttribute("listOfMyFriends", listOfMyFriends);
```

So that you can access the list of your friends using the key `"listOfMyFriends"`

Comment: @Capril Aprilovich You are welcome. Please accept the answer if this is want you were looking for.

Answer (score 2):

Add listOfMyFriends  to the Model as follows :

`model.addObject("listOfMyFriends ", listOfMyFriends );`